# Texture paint was working as expected, now is not

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have a weird issue I can't quite figure out. I was able to texture the handle, no issue, but I didn't notice until I started texturing the blade that I think my UVs were off. So I went back and "re-seamed" the full knife. Now all the islands are in place and not overlapping (as they were).

Now, however, as I try to paint the handle again, the texture is painting on very dark. Is there something I should have reset when I unwrapped the UV for a second time?

[image: dark texture paint over example]

I tried creating a new knife and handle in a different project, appended them to this one (since this is where the bulk of my work is.  I have "unlinked data block" in the left window with the UV islands.

I have "unlinked the data block" in the texture slot" for the handle.  Handle turns purple to confirm no texture attached.

I "unlocked the data block" for the texture image in the texture panel.

I have created a new image in the left window.

Now when I try to attach the knife image in the context area, I no longer have "texture" or even "brush" options. Kinda going insane here :O

[image: missing options in texture painter]

Thank you a ton in advance!

Ven

Comment: It's hard to know, but I doubt this has anything to do with your UVs. More likely, some texture paint brush setting is wrong somehow. I have a lot of trouble with this. Check into it and see what you can find. Also, step away from the whole thing for a while. Sometimes the answer will emerge when you stop trying so hard to find it.

Comment: @R-800 Thank you - I will poke around. It just seems odd that this would not be an issue on my very first go around, then, in a brand new project as well as the old, I am hitting these issues. I am not sure if I switched something unintentionally but I have been combing through the properties and such and nothing is landing for this complete noob.

Comment: @R-800 looks like it was settings alright. Somehow what I assume is "brightness" was turned down. No idea how because I didn't adjust it. That solved that issue. Then - when I went to paint another object, it was just as bright.... but painting on the opposite side! Lort help me, lol

Comment: This new "development" of yours... It sounds so very familiar... ;)

Comment: @R-800LOL I am sure it does!  Any thoughts on that? I did some digging and found "back face culling". I am not sure if that is the correct issue (again... in a place I never touched). Are there any other options that would 'turn on' back painting?Like, it wasn't painting both sides, it was only painting the back so I had to cheat a bit to get this tut done!

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure but, I do know that there is more than one backface culling feature. There's the one accessed from the viewport shading options, but there is another one under the materials tab. This probably isn't relevant, so it may not help much. Also, what you describe now almost sounds like it MAY be a UV issue after all (consider remapping it, or at least double checking the UV map for clues), or, maybe something that might happen from using a modifier of some kind (mirror?) and never applying it. Or FROM applying it prematurely. Who knows?

Comment: Can you check a few things - check your mesh face normals are pointing outward, check that your brush is set to 'mix' and not 'multiply' or 'darken', check for a linked image in your brush texture, and check to make sure you didn't press 'X' by mistake and swap brush colors inadvertently.

Comment: @CraigDJones it seems I had the brush "brightness" some how set to dark. My guess, I probably clicked "X" then if that is the shortcut to do so when using the brush!